# SQL: Trying to flag the earliest shipment date within a the same customer ID and order number across all rows of a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Think of an order fulfillment database where each customer ID can have the same Order Number for a product shipment and its refills. I am trying to flag the refills by adding 'Y' to a new column for refills. The first shipment is identified by the earliest ship date in the database for the same customer ID and order number. The shipments after the first shipment date with the same customer ID and order number would be the refills.

Customer # and Order # are varchars. Date is a date type.

Table I currently have. I want to be able to fill a new column called "Refill" with Y or N:

```
 Customer #      Order #      ShipDate        Refill <---New Column I want to create
   1234           2124       5/25/2015           Y          
   1234           2124       3/25/2015           N          
   1234           2124       4/25/2015           Y          
   5678           4439      12/25/2014           Y          
   5678           4439       2/20/2015           Y          
   5678           4439       9/10/2014           N         
   6666           5920       1/12/2012           Y
   6666           5920       5/12/2011           N         
   6666           6053       6/12/2016           Y
   6666           6053       4/12/2016           N
   6666           6053       8/12/2016           Y
```

Comment: Your data has a typo for order #2124 , there are two no values.

Comment: Your explanation does not correlate with the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the logic for the update is that the initial shipping record for a given customer and order is `"No"` but all subsequent records are `"Yes"`.

In the update query below I join your original table to a subquery which finds the initial shipping record for each customer/order group.  Then, a record in your original table which *does* match must be a `No` while a record which does not match must be a `Yes`.

```
UPDATE t1
SET Refill = CASE WHEN t2.Customer IS NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Customer, Order, MIN(ShipDate) AS ShipDate   -- this query finds
    FROM yourTable                                      -- the original
    GROUP BY Customer, Order                            -- ship date
) t2
    ON t1.Customer = t2.Customer AND
       t1.Order = t2.Order       AND
       t1.ShipDate = t2.ShipDate
WHERE t1.Order IS NOT NULL OR t1.ShipDate IS NOT NULL
```

This answer also assumes that you already have a `varchar` column called `Refill` defined.  If you don't, then go ahead and create one.

Comment: When I try this method I only get "N" in the row with the first ship date. The  rest is NULL rather than "Y" if it's a refill or NULL if the Shipdate or RX Number is NULL

Comment: @StackinAndSlackin Sorry I meant to use `LEFT JOIN`.  Please try the query again, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This works more or less. The issue with Left Join is that it adds a "Y" even when Order number & Ship date are NULL which is no good. In those instance it should remain NULL.

Comment: @StackinAndSlackin You can add a `WHERE` clause to handle this extra logic.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add the new field

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable Add Refill char(1) Not Null Default 'N';
```

Update rows in the table to set `Refill` if they are not the oldest `ShipDate` for that `Customer` and `Order` combination.

```
With cte As (
    SELECT Customer, [Order], ShipDate, Refill, RowNo = Row_Number() Over (Partition By Customer, [Order] Order By ShipDate Asc)
      From MyTable)
Update cte
   Set Refill = 'Y'
   Where RowNo <> 1;
```

Note that this has the advantage of handling cases where there were two shipments on the first date. We can't distinguish between them to say which one was first, but we will only mark one of them as 'N'.